# How to do a redirect to another rout in react?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

I'm working with react-image-mapper example (https://coldiary.github.io/react-image-mapper/)   on a photo, and I want to when I click on a shape, it redirect me to a another component (that has a rout). For example if I click on big rectangle (for example number 1) go to "/rectangles/".

I want to keep code structure, so I added redirect methods in the clicked(area) function. I have seen several ways on the net, which some of them are expired method, I couldn't do that at the end unfortunately. I'm confused as a react beginner.

Thanks for your help

That is the codes:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ImageMapper from "react-image-mapper";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import Rectangles from "./Rectangles";

import {  Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { hoveredArea: null, msg: null, moveMsg: null };

  load() {
    this.setState({ msg: "Interact with image !" });
  }
  clicked(area) {
    this.setState({
      msg: `You clicked on ${area.shape} at coords ${JSON.stringify(
        area.coords
      )} !`
    });
    return <Redirect to="/Rectangles/1" />;
  }
  clickedOutside(evt) {
    const coords = { x: evt.nativeEvent.layerX, y: evt.nativeEvent.layerY };
    this.setState({
      msg: `You clicked on the image at coords ${JSON.stringify(coords)} !`
    });
  }
  moveOnImage(evt) {
    const coords = { x: evt.nativeEvent.layerX, y: evt.nativeEvent.layerY };
    this.setState({
      moveMsg: `You moved on the image at coords ${JSON.stringify(coords)} !`
    });
  }
  enterArea(area) {
    this.setState({
      hoveredArea: area,
      msg: `You entered ${area.shape} ${area.name} at coords ${JSON.stringify(
        area.coords
      )} !`
    });
  }
  leaveArea(area) {
    this.setState({
      hoveredArea: null,
      msg: `You leaved ${area.shape} ${area.name} at coords ${JSON.stringify(
        area.coords
      )} !`
    });
  }


  getTipPosition(area) {
    return { top: `${area.center[1]}px`, left: `${area.center[0]}px` };
  }

  render() {
    let URL = "https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4052/4503898393_303cfbc9fd_b.jpg";
    let MAP = {
      name: "my-map",

    };
    return (
      <div className="grid">
        <div className="presenter">
          <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>

          </div>
          <pre className="message">
            {this.state.msg ? this.state.msg : null}
          </pre>
          <pre>{this.state.moveMsg ? this.state.moveMsg : null}</pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you are just returning some jsx, that jsx needs to be rendered. Return that `<Redirect .. />` from render conditionally. You will need to maintain a state, something like `shouldRedirect` and if that's true return `<Redirect .../>` from render. See this example: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: You are probably looking for `history.push('/rectangles/1')` as it is mentioned in react-router [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)

Comment: other simpler solution is `this.props.history.push('new/path')`

Comment: Vaibhav Vishal by history.push I receive this error: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Where you are setting `area` in state, why are you using `this.state.area.name`?

Comment: ravibagul91 it was my mistake, but problem is still exist. tnx

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions for redirect in react-router.

---

#### redirect in JSX (in render)

If you want to redirect in JSX you should use `Redirect` component.

```
<Redirect to='/rectangles/1'/>
```

> Rendering a  will navigate to a new location. The new location will override the current location in the history stack, like server-side redirects (HTTP 3xx) do. *Source: [react-router/Redirect](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md)*

---

#### redirect in function

If you want to redirect in function you should use `history.push()` function which is based on browsers history API. It is usually passed from router as a prop so the final solution would look like this:

```
this.props.history.replace('/rectangles/1');
```

In this situation your component (where you want to use history) must use `withRouter`. Something like this:

```
// import it
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

// export your component with router
export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

> "browser history" - A DOM-specific implementation, useful in web browsers that support the HTML5 history API *Source: [react-router/history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md)*

---

In case of need you can see [complete documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried the function way, I received this error : Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: @HashemRashtchi You have to use `withRouter` as is mentioned in documentation. I've provided a simple example. I hope it helps.